# Can not load the CLIPSLIB.dll file with Windows Service

Tags: c#, dll, windows-services, clips

I am working with developing Windows Service using C#. I want to load CLIPSLIB.dll with Windows Service. First I tried write service as console app in vs2010 placing CLIPSLIB.dll in the project debug folder. It worked fine.
But when I install it and run as Windows Service it throws this exception.

**Could not load file or assembly 'Mommosoft.ExpertSystem, Version=0.3.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=20382083c6694bdc' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.**

As I figured out this is happening because Windows Service is unable to load relevant dlls. So whare should I put external dlls to load with Windows Service?

Answer (score 1):

Scott Hanselman has an article that describes how to debug assembly loading errors. the downside to this method is that it requires a registry key change and a reboot in order to emable the fusion loader logging.

That article can be found here:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx

since you are writing a windows service check that the reference for the assembly refers to the bin directory and not some other path. Otherwise the fusion loader logs will identify where it is trying to load the assembly from.

as to the .dll files add a folder to your project and add the .dll files there, change the build properties from do not copy to copy if newer in order that the .dll files will end up in your build output bin path.

Answer (score 0):

You must rebuild the CLIPSLib solution,

1. Download all files in this link :
   Link:  https://svn.code.sf.net/p/clipsnet/code/

   2.Open CLIPSLib.sln in CLIPSLib folder

   3.Right-click on the solution and select rebuild solution.

   4.Go to the CLIPSLib folder your CLIPSLib.dll and CLIPSNet.dll is in ..\ ..\mlplatform\bin floder.

   hope this help.